# DatabaseError: ORA-12506: TNS:listener rejected connection based on service ACL filtering

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy, database-connection, oracle-autonomous-db

not able to connect to the DB hosted on oracle cloud: Autonomous Data Base (Warehousing) from python

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
user = 'admin'
password = '****'
tns = <string from the tnsnames.ora file>

engine = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://{0}:{1}@{2}'.format(user, password, tns))
con = engine.connect()
```

need to access the tables and data form the oracle database using python.

Comment: That error indicates the database has an access control list and your client is not part of that list.

Comment: Connections to ADB require use of an Oracle Wallet for SSL parameters. Is that part of your client configuration?

Comment: You can connect to ADB with or without wallets: using TLS or mTLS, respectively.   Update the question with more details about where Python is running, whether you are using a wallet or not, what version Oracle Client libraries you have.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add your IP address to the ACL list using "Add My Address" in the ACL options in oracle cloud.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZiF1.png)